# Migrate Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012 with Raid 5

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012, raid-5

What should i consider when migrating from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012.
I have a raid 5 configuration, so i don't want to lose any data (+/- 6 TB)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/ You should really ask this question at serverfault

Comment: Only if it is in a professional environment. 

Also the [SF] guys will not even open with:
"step 1: do you have a backup. step 2: did you test that backup". 

They just assume that have have and that you tested it.

Comment: @NicoJuicy: What has RAID5 to do with it (other than indicating that it is a really old installation or that you are short on diskspace). What would be different from any other upgrade from 2003 to 2012?